# Dovecot imap auth in large company

Tags: authentication, dovecot, imap

I manage email in large company. They have few emails, but lots of employees who read them.

Every email is read from 10+ employees.

At the moment, we use password auth and if someone left the company, we had to change the password on each employee.

How I can simplify this, but without changing the setup too much?

One way (I don't like it) is to do certificate for each employee and use certificates to login. Then if someone leave the company, I just remove the certificate.

Other way would be to use SQL database with the passwords. Because it is external to Dovecot, I can do there whatever I want, for example I can do password like "john.smith::secret" then I can check against SQL.
However, I prefer not to add SQL database to the server.

Any other possibilities?
Something easy and fast like SQL, but without using SQL database...

Comment: Why do you have to change all passwords? Coworkers are sharing passwords? In that case, you might look at [shared mailboxes](https://wiki.dovecot.org/SharedMailboxes).

Comment: yes, they share passwords. co workers does not have their own emails, they read emails like info@ and office@